# как сделать функцию, которая будет принимать ссылку на DOM объект?

Tags: javascript, dom

Сделайте функцию appendElem, которая первым параметром будет принимать ссылку на DOM объект, в котором лежит тег ul, а вторым - текст. Сделайте так, чтобы данная функция создавала новую li с переданным текстом и добавляла ее в конец переданного тега ul. */
не получается заполучить ссылку на dom объект, подскажите, что я неправильно делаю? первый раз сталкиваюсь с подобными функциями

```js
let ul = document.getElementById("list");
function appendElem(elems, text) {
  for (let elem of elems) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
     li.textContent = text;
    elem.textContent += li;
     ul.innerHTML = li;
  }
}

console.log(appendElem(li, "text"));
console.log(elems);
```

```html
    <ul id="list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> что я неправильно делаю

Много чего. Пунктов 5-6 точно наберётся

1. Надо передать ссылку на `ul`, а вы передается на `li`. Причём которого не объявлено в коде
2. Цикл не прокатит, т.к. если передать ссылку на **один** элемент DOM, то, логично, никаких итераций у него нет
3. Передаёте в функцию `elems`, но при этом пытаетесь обратиться к `ul`, которого нет в данной функции
4. Зачем вообще цикл, если нужно сделать добавление элемента в конец?
5. зачем вот это `elem.textContent += li`? если по условию нет надобности заменять текст в других `li`
6. `console.log(elems);` - что вы хотели увидеть, если у вас `elems` внутри функции?

```js
let ul = document.getElementById("list");

function appendElem(ul, text) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = text;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

appendElem(ul, "text")
appendElem(ul, "hello")
appendElem(ul, "yo")
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Алексей, можете еще подсказать по поводу этой задачи, правильно я ее решил?
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let ul = document.getElementById("list");

function appendElem(elems, text) {
 for (let elem of arr){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text + elem;
  elems.appendChild(li);
 }
}
(appendElem(ul, "text"));

Comment: как минимум надо arr передать в функцию...... и вместо elems писать ul, чтобы самого себя с толку не сбивать

Comment: имеете ввиду массив переместить во внутрь функции? у меня же есть ul, которая содержит ссылку на элементы, если я буду писать ul вместо elems, то мне кажется так еще больше запутаюсь
`let ul = document.getElementById("list");

function appendElem(ul, text) {
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 for (let elem of arr){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text + elem;
  ul.appendChild(li);
 }
}
(appendElem(ul, "number "));` скорее всего так

Comment: ul содержит ссылку на **один элемент** на ul........ ..."массив переместить во внутрь функции" --- не вовнутрь, а передать как аргумент........ потому что если игнорировать передачу, тогда зачем вообще в функции аргументы?)

Comment: `let ul = document.getElementById("list");

function appendElem(ul, text, arr) {
 for (let elem of arr){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text + elem;
  ul.appendChild(li);
 }
}
(appendElem(ul, "number ", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));`